# Search in Json for string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to look for certain values in my Json.

Search for the type "patientSize" and find the value of the "coveredText".

Actually, the console throws out *found:[]*

Since I have to perform some searches, I am looking for a fast and high-performance possibility. Thank you for your tips.

**Example JSON**

```
{
"annoDs": [
     {
        "begin": 512,
        "end": 518,
        "type": "patientSize",
        "coveredText": "183 cm",
        "additionalParameters": {
            "unit": "Zentimeter",
            "value": "183"
        }

    }
]
```

}

**JS**

```
var data = JSON.parse(retrievedAnnotation);
setTimeout(function() {

function getAge(code) {
  return data.annoDs.filter(
      function(data){
        return data.code == code;
        }
  );
}

var found = getAge('patientSize');
console.log("found:", found);
}, 50);
```

Comment: `code !== type`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `getAge` must be like this

```
function getAge(code) {
  return data.annoDs.filter(function(data) {
    return data.type === code;
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can use `map` to to get an array of `coverdText`

```
function getAge(code) {
  return data.annoDs
    .filter((data) => data.type === code)
    .map((e) => e.coveredText);
}
```

Comment: Thank you IzumiSy!

Comment: One more question. Now I find the object, but how can I get the value of the "coveredText"? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, my IDE (Aptana) throws a "unexpected token"-issue for the => . But the code works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are searching for the property "code" of each element in annoDs.

You have:

```
data.code == code; // undefined != 'patientSize'
```

You should have:

```
function getAge(code) {
    return data.annoDs.filter(
        function(data){
            return data.type == code;
        }
    );
}

var found = getAge('patientSize');
found.forEach(el => console.log(el.coveredText));
```

Note that **filter** will return every element the matching the condition.
You should use **find** if you know that there's only one object matching the condition, because it will return the first element matching the condition.